# Material sidebar isn't displaying default options

Tags: rendering, materials

I'm new to blender but I'm trying to add eyebrows etc onto a mask I've created. The problem is following videos when going onto materials they get options such as specular and diffuse all in separate tabs when they create a material. I don't. I do when I create a new blender and with the cube selecting materials I get all of those different drop down tabs so it's not a version issue.

But with my mask at the moment under materials I only get - diffuse, surface, volume, displacement  and it also doesn't display the color I select onto my object.  I know its a probably a silly little thing I've done but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the render engine is set to *[Cycles](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles)*, but the tutorial is using *Blender Internal*.

You can change the render engine in the *info header* at the top of the window:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I had been looking so much to figure out what it was. So simple -_-

Comment: @Tom Glad to help :) If this answer satisfactorily answered your question, consider marking it as accepted by clicking the checkmark below the voting icons.